# Existing OS drive into different computer to restore files

Tags: windows-10, boot, file-transfer

I have an older desktop computer (pc1) with a 1TB SSD with windows 10 pro on the hard drive and it won't load windows. I bought a new desktop (pc2) with windows 10 pro. I would like to remove the SSD from pc1 and plug it into pc2 internally using a sata cable.

Is there anything special I need to do to make sure windows 10 loads from the new SSD and not the drive from pc1?

Just to clarify... I do not want to run windows from pc1 on pc2. I need to get files off of the drive from PC1. I simply want to connect it to PC to so I can transfer files from it.

Here is some context for my question:

With pc1 a few months ago I bought a larger drive. Disconnected my existing os drive. Installed a fresh copy of windows 10 pro. After everything was setup and working I turned the computer off and connected the original os drive to transfer my files. I went into the bios to make sure the boot drive was the new drive. Windows loaded and I transferred my files. Then I powered down and disconnected the original os drive. Then when I booted the system windows 10 would get stuck on the loading screen. I tried re-connecting the old drive and it would still hang at the same point.

I went through 3 hours worth of different commands and recovery steps and could not get windows to load.

Back in the windows xp days this I would use internal drives as a means of backup and never once ran into this problem.

I'm hoping this was some kind of issue related to pc1.

Comment: You won't be able to use an system drive from System A, on System B, if they are not similar.  You can sysprep the system drive from System A, and this would allow you to use it on System B, but that requires System A to be functional.  There is also third-party software that you can use to image the system drive from System A, in order to restore it on System B, allowing you to clone the HDD. Any of these solutions will require you to change the license key of the installation though.

Comment: When you "went into the bios to make sure the boot drive was the new drive." Did you actually change anything? Or did you just look at it, it looked correct, and exit without saving changes? Or did you manually selected a boot drive upon exit?

Comment: @Carlin Baert "Is there anything special I need to do to make sure windows 10 loads from the new SSD and not the drive from pc1?" Can solve it if you provide make and model of the desktop PC #2 (need to look up its BIOS menu options). Please click [edit] and add that to the original question; please don't use Add Comment, use [edit] instead.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to remove PC1-SSD, connect it to a SATA port on PC2, power up and go into BIOS/Firmware to make the PC1-SSD the top boot device.

There will be a Boot Maintenance menu item (that's what it's called in Gigabyte AMI BIOS menu) which lets you list which drives are used to boot and in which order. It should show "Windows Boot Manager on XXXXXXXX" (where XXXXXXX is the model number of the drive).

There may also be a key to use after the Power On Self Test (F10 in Gigabytes and Intel desktops) which lets you pick which drive to boot from.